# Access I2C on i.mx6 board from Android app

Tags: android, linux, i2c, su, nxp-microcontroller

I am working on a development board based on nxp i.mx6 (Variscite Dart mx6).

My application is signed with platform keys and I can see it running as sharedUserId (UID 1000).

When I try ti execute the "su" command with getRuntime.exec("/system/xbin/su") an exception error Is rised (permissione denied).

I need the su to being able to use Shell commands i2cset and i2cset.

I am using Android Oreo 8.0.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating a simple daemon being launched on boot that receive the commands to execute by the Java app (through socket).

Below I report daemon code (it's very simple for now, but it works).

Luca

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>



int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    size_t addrlen, n;
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr); 
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(2000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    while(1)
    {
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, (void*)buffer, 100, 0,
        (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (int *) &addrlen);
        buffer[n] = '\n';
        system(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```